# Access directive method from the angularjs service

Tags: angularjs

I have method in directive here i need to access this method from angularjs service.

For Example:

Service,

```
angular.module('myServiceModule', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope','notify', function($scope, notify) {}]).service('notify', ['$window',function(win) {            
}]);
```

Directive,

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', []).controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {}]).directive('myCustomer', function($scope) {
    $scope.enableEditor = function(){ 
    } 
    return {
        template: 
    };
});
```

In my project i need to access directive method from angularjs.
For example i have added sample code.
In directive i have enableEditor() method i need to be access this method form my angular services.
I searched on web i did not get proper solution for accessing directive method from angular service.

Comment: directive and service are two different things. why you need to call the directives method?

Comment: In my project i have custom directive for dropdown filed this directive i used whole application. but problem is this dropdown is overlap for next dropdown i had some idea so i asked